# Equivalent condition for a cardinal number to be of cofinality $\aleph_0$

Tags: set-theory

Let cf$(\alpha)$ denotes the co-final of the transfinite cardinal number $\alpha.$
For every successor cardinal $\alpha$ we have cf$(\alpha)=\alpha\neq \aleph_0.$
Thus cf$(\alpha) = \aleph_0,$ implies $\alpha$ is a limit cardinal.

We can find some limit cardinal number $\alpha,$ for example $\alpha=\aleph_{\omega}$ with cf$(\alpha)=\aleph_0.$ Now, can we fined all (limit) cardinal numbers which satisfies 
cf$(\alpha)=\aleph_0?$

Comment: $\aleph_\omega$ has cofinality $\aleph_0$, but $\aleph_{\omega_1}$ has cofinality $\aleph_1$. At least assuming the axiom of choice.

Comment: Prove that $\operatorname{cf}(\aleph_\alpha)=\operatorname{cf}(\alpha)$ for limit ordinals (although cofinality of arbitrary ordinals is easier to measure with order types rather than cardinals, but for initial ordinals it is the same).

Comment: OK! I wrote wrong. But, is there an equivalent condition for cf$(\alpha)=\aleph_0?$

Comment: I don't understand your last two comments. At all. My second comment provides an equivalent definition. It is not predicative, since you can have $\aleph_\alpha=\alpha$ with cofinality $\aleph_0$.

Answer (score 1):

Asaf Karagila has essentially answered this question in comments (and if he posts an answer I'll delete this one for precedence reasons), but let me flesh it out a bit.

Remember that cofinality makes sense for *arbitrary infinite limit ordinals*, not just infinite cardinals. The characterization is:

> $\aleph_\alpha$ has cofinality $\omega$ iff $\alpha=0$ or $\alpha$ *(is a limit ordinal and)* has cofinality $\omega$.

*As an aside, remember that $\aleph_\alpha$ and $\omega_\alpha$ are literally the same thing, the difference between the notation is merely that the former indicates that we're thinking about only **cardinals** while the second indicates that we're thinking about **general ordinals**. I'm going to use both notations since in this particular question I think it will be clearer, but really I think the ideal approach is to ditch the $\aleph$-notation completely except for situations when we're using cardinal arithmetic - that is cardinal addition, multiplication, and exponentiation (which we're not doing here).*

So, for example, the cardinals $\aleph_\omega, \aleph_{\omega^3+\omega^2\cdot 13}$, and $\aleph_{\omega_{\omega_\omega}}$ each have cofinality $\omega$, while $\aleph_{37}$ and $\aleph_{\omega_1}$ do not since $cf(37)=1$ and $cf(\omega_1)=\omega_1$.

Proving the fact above is a good exercise; here are a couple hints:

- In the right-to-left direction, suppose $cf(\alpha)=\omega$. Let $(\beta_i)_{i\in\omega}$ be cofinal in $\alpha$; what can you say about the sequence $(\aleph_{\beta_i})_{i\in\omega}$?
- In the left-to-right direction, we do the same thing but in the other direction. Suppose $\aleph_\alpha$ has cofinality $\omega$ and $\alpha\not=0$. Let $(\aleph_{\beta_i})_{i\in\omega}$ be cofinal in $\aleph_\alpha$: what can you say about the sequence $(\beta_i)_{i\in\omega}$, and what does that tell us about $\alpha$?